How to use callback to complete the task?
I have a method that returns immediately and accepts callback function when the job is done:
public static void CommandCompleteFunction(ulong taskID)
{
    ...
}

_taskID = device.MoveTo(position, CommandCompleteFunction);

How can I wrap this in order to return Task result whenever callback is called? Result(true/false) is determined inside callback.

Why do you want a Task? A Task isn't an alternative to callbacks, it's a promise that something will complete in the future. In Javascript the equivalent feature is actually called Promise. A static void doesn't return anything either, so where would true/false come from? await on the other hand removes the need for callbacks after a task completes

BTW what's the code that needs to be executed ? You could use Task.Run(()=>ThatCode()); to run it on another thread. If you use await Task.Run(()=>..); the code after that line will execute once the task completes, as if it were a callback.

@PanagiotisKanavos I think they're just asking how to adapt the callback-based API to one that uses TPL.

You might want to pay attention to error handling. If there is any chance that MoveTo throws an exception there should be some way to propagate this back to the caller.

If MoveTo blocks, the wrapper will block as well. Dai's answer works if MoveTo doesn't block. If it does, the call should be run in the background, eg using Task.Run.

Use TaskCompletionSource:
public static Task MoveToAsync( this Device d, Position pos )
{
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    
    device.MoveTo( pos, ( UInt64 taskId ) => tcs.SetResult() );

    return tcs.Task;
}

Used like so:
await device.MoveToAsync( position );

I assume the taskId returned from your device.Move method is for tracking state via the callbacks, but the TaskCompletionSource does that for us so my code above doesn't use it.

You should probably show how to handle exceptions too. For this code to work MoveTo shouldn't block. Otherwise callers of MoveToAsync will block or even deadlock. Task.Run inside MoveToAsync can handle that. The OP should specify the actual case because there's no way to write one method that decides whether to use Task.Run by itself

@PanagiotisKanavos I assume MoveTo is non-blocking, otherwise it wouldn't use a callback in the first place.

Some hardware devices are controlled by polling or sleeping, eg raise a pin to 5V for X ms. The very fact the API doesn't even use Begin/End or events makes me suspect it's a minimal wrapper over a DLL. And I've seen some very bad implementations.

This is a good answer. I can't see a scenario where the MoveToAsync would deadlock. In case the device.MoveTo does something more after calling the callback, this something might be postponed until all await continuations of the resulting Task have completed. This might be an argument for configuring the TaskCompletionSource with the TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously option.


How can I wrap this in order to return Task result whenever callback is called?

Here is a simple generic implementation of such a wrapper:
public static Task<TResult> TaskFromAction<TArg, TResult>(
    Func<TArg, TResult> action, out Action<TArg> callback)
{
    TArg argument = default;
    Task<TResult> task = new Task<TResult>(() => action(argument));
    callback = arg =>
    {
        argument = arg;
        task.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    };
    return task;
}

This method takes an action delegate that contains the logic you would normally put in the CommandCompleteFunction, and returns two things:

Another delegate that is named callback, and is intended to be given as argument to the device.MoveTo method.
A Task that represents the completion of the action. This Task will start running on the ThreadPool when the device.MoveTo has invoked the callback delegate.

Usage example:
Task<bool> task = TaskFromAction((ulong taskID) =>
{
    //... here decide whether you should return true or false.
    return true;
}, out Action<ulong> callback);

_taskID = device.MoveTo(position, callback);

bool result = await task;

This is not a super optimized implementation, because the TaskFromAction contains a couple of variable-capturing delegates. This shouldn't be a problem in practice, unless you call the device.MoveTo very very frequently.
It is assumed that the device.MoveTo invokes the callback only once. In case the callback is invoked more than once and on different threads in a 32-bit machine, the action could receive a torn ulong argument. In other words this TaskFromAction implementation is not 100% thread-safe.
It should be noted that in case the device.MoveTo fails to invoke the callback, the task will never complete, and the execution flow will get stuck forever in the await task; line.
